# Limit price field of type Text/Numeric to only numbers and with a minimum of 4

Tags: civimember, price-sets

Is it possible to enforce a numbers only input with a numerical minimum on a `Text/Numeric` price field? I'm guessing it could be done with jQuery, but I would rather have this set up in the Civi Admin UI, since it would be much cleaner.

**More details:**

I have a price field set up like this:

[image]

*On the front end, it looks like this:* *(but I want 4 to be the lowest allowed number, with no letters input)*

[image]

Basically, I want the HTML equal of `<input type="number" min="4"/>` in the cleanest and safest way possible. *(safe as in not hacking up some jQuery and then moving an element 3 months later and breaking it)*

Answer (score 2):

Ideally you would develop a little extension that uses the validateForm hook (check https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_validateForm/). This will allow you to refuse input that does not meet your criteria.